# Render a JTable for specifc cells inside of another JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to render JTables in the cells of an outer JTable. The `ALLYTIPS`, `ENEMYTIPS`, `STATS`, `SPELLS`, and `PASSIVE` rows will all have JTables for their corresponding `Value` (the name of the column) cell.

Here is what the outer JTable currently looks like:

[image: Here is what the outer JTable currently looks like]

What is the best way to render JTables for these cells? I created a custom `TableCellRenderer` that overrides `getTableCellRendererComponent`which looks like this:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component component = null;
        if(column == 1) {
            switch(row) {
                case 3: case 4: {
                    List<String> tips = (List)value;
                    TipsTableModel tableModel = new TipsTableModel(tips);
                    component = new JTable(tableModel);
                    break;
                }
                case 5: {
                    ChampionStats stats = (ChampionStats)value;
                    StatsTableModel tableModel = new StatsTableModel(stats);
                    component = new JTable(tableModel);
                    break;
                }
                case 6: {
                    HashMap<String, ChampionSpell> spells = (HashMap)value;
                    SpellsTableModel tableModel = new SpellsTableModel(spells);
                    component = new JTable(tableModel);
                    break;
                }
                case 7: {
                    String[] passive = (String[])value;
                    PassiveTableModel tableModel = new PassiveTableModel(passive);
                    component = new JTable(tableModel);
                    break;
                }
                default: component = null;
            }
        }
        return component;
    }
```

and the code for the outer table that sets the `TableCellRenderer` for each cell:

```
for(int i = 0; i < championTableInfo.getRowCount(); i++) {
                Object value = championTableInfo.getValueAt(i, 1);
                javax.swing.JTable cell = (javax.swing.JTable)renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(championTableInfo, value, false, false, i, 1);
                championTableInfo.setValueAt(cell, i, 1);
            }
```

which does nothing.

I have custom `TableModel`s for each of the objects in the cells for which I want to render JTables.

It looks like I may need to use `getCellRenderer` on the outer `JTable` object but I'm not exactly sure how to do that. Or do I need to render the cell directly in the `getValueAt` method of the `TableModel` of the outer JTable?

Comment: The inner table should be part of the renderer and its data can be nested Vectors or a TableModel. Keep model and views separate.

Comment: Having said that, I would avoid doing this if it were my code. Consider having 2 JTables, a master table and a detail one, the detail table changing when the master's selected cell changes.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter the two tables might be a good idea. Any particular reason for this approach? Just ease-of-use when viewing the table?

Comment: A JTable as a renderer will have very limited functionality, especially with regards to responding to mouse clicks and cell selections. You would also have to make it an editor, and it just seems like needless complexity.

Comment: If you haven't already seen it, perhaps this will be helpful: [Displaying a jTable inside another jTable](https://blog.marcnuri.com/displaying-a-jtable-inside-another-jtable-jtable-cellrenderer/)